# In Facebook, how can I remove a tag of a friend in my photo?

Tags: facebook

I accidentally tagged the wrong person in one of my photos that I posted. How can I go into the post and remove that person from being tagged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to Photos in the left navigation bar
2. Click on an Album
3. Click on a Picture > a pop-up will appear with the picture on the left and comments and options on the right
4. There's an Edit button under the comments section > Click that
5. That will allow you to edit the comment if you have one, and the tags.
6. Each tag is in it's own blue box with an 'x' > click the 'x'
7. The tag will be removed > Click 'Done Editing' to finish

Answer (score 1):

1. Simply go to the photo where you added the tag.
2. The photo will open in a pop-up window  with the title of the photo and below that there will be the list of tagged names in a blue font with the person's name.
3. If you hover the mouse arrow on the tag a small pop-up will open, with an option "Remove tag".
4. Click on that to remove the tag, and the tag is removed.